# How to get the sum-value without making its local

Tags: r, sparkr

In SparkR I have a DataFrame `u` that contains

```
'amount' = 231,2,324,1213 ...
```

To calculate the sum in sparkR I use

```
summa <- agg(u, amount="sum")
```

Now `summa` is a DataFrame. I want to know the value of `summa` and I can get that value by typing `head(summa)` or `collect(summa)` but this takes about 2 min to do. How can I get the value faster? Or how can I use `summa` as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason that `head(summa)` is slow, is not because of the `head` function, rather it's because lazy evaluation is at play. That is, we don't calculate `summa` (and so use `agg`), **until** we call the `head` function. When you call `head` you also get the overhead of calling `agg`.